# Using PureComponents in presentational/container pattern

Tags: reactjs

There is old [article](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) by Dan Abramov about splitting component in container and presentational part.

What I don't see in any article about this React pattern is usage of PureComponent for presentational component.

Is there any reason I should not use PureComponent by default for every presentational component?

Comment: Because PureComponent takes longer to write? It's unnecessary that the use of PureComponent will result in performance improvement. Functional components are already fast enough in React 16.

Answer (score 0):

If your React component’s render() function renders the same result given the same props and state, you can use React.PureComponent for a performance boost in some cases.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent